# How to iterate over a GROUP_CONCAT column to compare

Tags: mysql

If I have a column with a set of numbers (1, 4, 6, 8, 12), how can I iterate over it to see whether the next number is greater or small than the previous?

I need to create a column that then either outputs true or false.

The column in question is **amounts**.

```
SELECT
MONTHNAME(t1.processingTime) AS month,
t1.holder,
t1.json->>'$.payload.customer.email' AS email,
t1.json->>'$.payload.customer.phone' AS phone,
t1.json->>'$.payload.billing.country' AS country,
t1.bin,
t1.last4Digits,
GROUP_CONCAT(t1.amount ORDER BY t1.processingTime) AS amounts,
GROUP_CONCAT(t1.processingTime ORDER BY t1.processingTime) AS dates,
COUNT(t1.id) AS count
FROM transactions t1
WHERE t1.channelUuid = '8acda4cc6ade5ae2016ae92bb6965076'
AND paymentType = 'DB'
GROUP BY month, t1.holder, t1.bin, t1.last4Digits, email HAVING count > 3
ORDER BY MONTH(t1.processingTime), count DESC
```

Comment: Define next and previous. Are you comparing only 12 with only 8?

Comment: For me it sounds like: "How do I get the desired result using the wrong tool for my task". See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to compare 1 to 4, 4 to 6, 8 to 12, etc. I may have gone about this the wrong way but what would be an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Not sure about "efficient", but with MySQL 8.0 you could use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` in a subquery. What is your version? And how should the result look like? Better yet create sample data and expected result.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel is pretty right here consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ATtmqDd5b8jWLCAxueW4e/8) thats some tricky SQL to compare GROUP_CONCAT generated values to one and other.. Using that incombination with your current query is even harder..

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for better answers..